# .NET MVC - Storing database result during single page result?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, variables

Fairly simple issue which is solved in PHP by using a static variable.

```
private static $pages;
public function Pages() {
    if($pages == null) {
        $pages = new PageCollection();
        $pages->findAll();
    }
}
```

Everywhere in my code I use Pages()::someFindFunction() to make sure the results are fetched only once, and I use that same collection.

I want the same in my .NET MVC application: use something like:

```
<%=MySite.Pages.findById(1).Title%>
```

In the code below, if I use a private variable, or if I use a public class with shared variables (doesn't matter) they are both persisted during the entire application.

**I want them to load the same way PHP does, once per request. Now where do I store the .NET equivalent of *private static* `$pages`, so that the code below works?**

```
            //what to do with $pages??

Public Module MySite
    Public Function Pages() As PageCollection
        If $pages Is Nothing Then
            $pages.loadAll()
        End If
        Return $pages
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: Just to confirm, are the values you want to cache user specific or global?

Comment: User specific, just one single request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st, are you sure you want a module? Normally, you'd use a class.

```
Public Class MySiteController
    Private _pages as PageCollection
    ReadOnly Property Pages As PageCollection 
        Get
          If _pages Is Nothing Then 
            _pages = New PageCollection
            _pages.FindAll
          End If 
          Return _pages 
        End Get 
    End Function 

    ... other code here...

    '' use it as:  Pages.FindById(1)
End Class
```

Comment: Fine, but where does the class live? It needs to be instantiated doesn't it?

Comment: Ah, I see. If you are doing MVC, the class can be your controller.

Comment: But what happens if you start mixing up controller requests?

Comment: It's my understanding that a controller is instantiated for each request.  So if you have multiple concurrent requests, they get different instances, and different PageCollections. If you want the PageCollection to be scoped to a session, so that multiple concurrent requests from the same browser would use the same PageCollection, and use it across multiple requests, then you should stuff the PageCollection into Session State.

Comment: I'm confused. I really don't mean 'sharing between requests'. But just use a globally referenced variable everywhere in code. I understand this is very bad design, but why is this so hard to do? Isn't is just possible to create a request-scoped static variable?

Comment: Actually I did need an application wide reference, however a wrong call somewhere made something messed up... I had two caches running: AllPages() and AllPages(cultureCode). See where I'm going? I was editing the AllPages() reference while using AllPages(cultureCode) everywhere on the site :)